# How to check Httpclient Download speed in C#?

Tags: c#, httpclient

The Webclient class was able to measure the speed with the following code:

```
    ConcurrentQueue<long> bytes = new ConcurrentQueue<long>();
    long before = 0;
    private async void WebClientDownload(string url,string filepath)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                bytes.Enqueue(e.BytesReceived - before);
                before = e.BytesReceived;                   
            };
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, filepath);
        }
    }
    private async void MeasureSpeed()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            long val,sum = 0;
            while (bytes.TryDequeue(out val)) sum += val;
            sum /= 1024;
            //Print : Speed= sum KB/s
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

However, as the Httpclient class seems to be faster, I want to use this class. Unlike WebClient, HttpClient does not know the bytes it has received so far without the ProgressChanged event.

Is there a way in HttpClient to know how many bytes have been received so far, such as the WebClient's ProgressChanged event?

Answer (score 0):

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    Console.WriteLine("Download Started");
                    totalBytes = client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize;

                    for (; ; )
                    {
                        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                        {
                            await Task.Yield();
                            break;
                        }

                        receivedBytes += bytesRead;

                        int received = unchecked((int)receivedBytes);
                        int total = unchecked((int)totalBytes);

                        double percentage = ((float)received) / total;
                        Console.WriteLine(received / (1024) + "Kb / " + total / (1024 )+" Kb");
                        Console.WriteLine("Completed : " + percentage + "%");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. This has the same effect as Webclient's ProgressChanged.

Comment: then what you want exactly?

Comment: Yes. I have already adapted this code to my situation. But apart from that, there is one thing I want to know. ReadAsync on a stream in memory with GetResponseStream means downloading resources from the web? Until I wrote this article, the moment I got the stream with GetResponseStream, I thought I was no longer communicating with the web.